# Base HSQLDB Query Nested Sub-Query/Sub-Set Problems

Tags: hsqldb

I'm relatively new to databases and LibreOffice Base/HSQLDB. I have the latest Base installed.
My biking database has 1 table "BikeDate" with 4 fields as follows:

```
| RideID | RideDate | Bike | Miles |
 1        10/2/97    Y22    15.6
....... with say 620 entries
```

What I am trying to obtain is a comparison of the monthly rides over the last 17 years. My metrics would be the sum of all the rides for each month across all the years, then the average ride during each month across all the years, then the sum of the miles for each month for 2014 and the average ride for each month for 2014.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT MONTH( "RideDate" ) AS "MONTH", SUM( "Miles" ) AS "SUM of Miles", AVG( "Miles" ) AS "AVG of Miles", 
( SELECT SUM( "Miles" ) FROM "BikeDate" WHERE ( YEAR( "RideDate" ) = '2014' ) ORDER BY MONTH( "RideDate" ) ) AS "Sum 2014", 
( SELECT AVG( "Miles" ) FROM "BikeDate" WHERE ( YEAR( "RideDate" ) = '2014' ) ORDER BY MONTH( "RideDate" ) ) AS "Avg 2014" 
FROM "BikeDate" AS "BikeDate" 
GROUP BY MONTH( "RideDate" ) 
ORDER BY MONTH( "RideDate" ) ASC
```

With output of:

```
|MONTH | Sum of Miles | AVG of Miles | Sum 2014 | AVG 2014 |
 2     | 12.2         | 6.1          | 29       | 14.5     |   
 3     | 217.9        | 10.38        | 29       | 14.5     |
 4     | 744.3        | 12.2         | 29       | 14.5     |
 5     | 1316.3       | 17.55        | 29       | 14.5     |
....                                 
 12    | 70.2         | 11.7         | 29       | 14.5     |
```

First: Can this be done? Both 2014 columns for month 2 should be zero (we had 48" of snowfall for a current total of 338"). How can I get this to work? I'd like to stay in LO Base because its free and currently installed.

Thanks, Dave.

Answer (score 1):

This looks quite difficult to achieve with HSQLDB 1.8 database that is bundled with LO Base. You can use the latest HSQLDB 2.3.x as an external database with LO. This version allows you to use the expression below for the current year:

```
AVG ("Miles") FILTER (WHERE YEAR("RideDate") = 2014)
```

You can use this and a similar expression for SUM alongside the SUM and AVG expressions in the main select. There won't be a need to use additional sub-select queries.

```
SELECT MONTH( "RideDate" ) AS "MONTH", 
  SUM( "Miles" ) AS "SUM of Miles", 
  AVG( "Miles" ) AS "AVG of Miles", 
  SUM( "Miles" ) FILTER (WHERE YEAR("RideDate") = 2014) AS "Sum 2014", 
  AVG( "Miles" ) FILTER (WHERE YEAR("RideDate") = 2014) AS "Avg 2014" 
 FROM "BikeDate" AS "BikeDate" 
 GROUP BY MONTH( "RideDate" ) 
 ORDER BY MONTH( "RideDate" ) ASC
```

Check the http://www.oooforum.org and other resources for the "split database" solution for using the latest HSQLDB with LO.